# Input skips from A to B and both printed in same line. MacOS C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char nameuser[12];
  int userChoice;

  printf("Name(Max. 12 Characters): ");
  gets(nameuser);

  do{
    char messageuser[127];
    FILE *fptr;

    printf("Message: ");
    gets(messageuser);

    fptr = fopen("/Users/exampleuser/Desktop/Test/chat.txt", "a");
    fprintf(fptr, "%s: %s\n", nameuser, messageuser);
    fclose(fptr);

    printf("Another Message? Yes = 1, No = 0: ");
    scanf("%d", &userChoice);
  }while(userChoice == 1);

  return 0;
}
```

Here is my Code. It works on GNU/Linux fine but not on Mac. Heres how it should work:

```
Name: John
Message: Hello Guys!
Another Message? Yes = 1, No = 0: 1
Name... and so on until I stop it.
```

But here's how it actually works on my Mac:

```
Name: John
Message: Hello Guys!
Another Message? Yes = 1, No = 0: 1
Message: Another Message? Yes = 1, No = 0:
```

Why does it behave the way it does?
I apologise for my English.

Comment: it shouldn't work on both systems. `scanf("%d"`, then `gets(..)` - and who reads the newline between `scanf` and `gets`?

Comment: But how can I fix it? I'm sitting here all day trying to figure it out. As you can already see I'm new to C.

Comment: Read the newline. `scanf("%d\n"...`

Comment: When I try to read the newline I can't continue. It won't load the do while loop after scanf("%d\n"...

Comment: I'm stuck in a kind of a loop. I can only press enter and it does nothing.

Comment: `fopen` can fail, but your code doesn't check this.

Comment: `I can only press enter and it does nothing.` - insert a number. `scanf` will read up any leading whitespace (newline, spaces, tabs) until it reads a number (consecutive string of digits)

Comment: When I enter a number the code crashes

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems in your program

- you mix *gets* and *scanf("%d")* so as it was said in remarks you will get empty lines
- the use of *gets* is dangerous because there no protection against buffer overflow, use *fgets*
- you say *Max. 12 Characters* but in fact it is 11 because you need place for the ending null character
- you do not check the result of *gets* and *scanf*
- you do not check the result of *fopen*
- is not gentle to ask for 0/1 while the goal is Y/N
- *gets* (and *fgets*) returns the \n when it is read but you probably do not want it

Here is a proposal taken into account the previous remarks :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char nameuser[12];
  int userChoice;

  printf("Name(Max. %d Characters): ", sizeof(nameuser) - 1);
  if (fgets(nameuser, sizeof(nameuser), stdin) == NULL)
    return 0;

  char * p = strchr(nameuser, '\n');

  if (p != NULL)
    *p = 0;

  for (;;) {
    char messageuser[127];

    printf("Message(Max. %d Characters): ", sizeof(messageuser) - 1);
    if (fgets(messageuser, sizeof(messageuser), stdin) == NULL)
      return 0;

    if ((p = strchr(messageuser, '\n')) != NULL)
      *p = 0;

    FILE * fptr = fopen("chat.txt", "a");

    if (fptr == NULL) {
      printf("cannot open file");
      return 0;
    }

    fprintf(fptr, "%s: %s\n", nameuser, messageuser);
    fclose(fptr);

    printf("Another Message? Y/N: ");
    if ((fgets(messageuser, sizeof(messageuser), stdin) == NULL) ||
    (*messageuser != 'Y'))
      return 0;
  }
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra q.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ rm -f chat.txt
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Name(Max. 11 Characters): me
Message(Max. 126 Characters): this is me
Another Message? Y/N: Y
Message(Max. 126 Characters): and nobody else
Another Message? Y/N: N
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat chat.txt 
me: this is me
me: and nobody else
```

Note : I accept empty name and messages, and spaces at the beginning/end, I let you to fix that, else too easy ...